# hide .php extension from address bar also open a page without .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want open my page without .php extension like www.myweb.com/guest and also hide .php from address bar if user go to any page of my web. I tried many way to remove it to see these web [link1](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) and [link2](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php) and many post on `StackOverflow` web but these are not working.

My domain from Godaddy And hosting from ONELANCER here Apache Version   2.2.27 PHP Version  5.4.28

Please give me a guideline.

I tried to add these into my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

also

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

and also

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

and also

#RewriteEngine on#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank u Its work well but in few page show "You don't have permission to access /mypagename/ on this server.  Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: mypagename have a directory also, should I change it? Without change have any way please?

Comment: Now its show page without any css and js. and display address bar http://myweb.com/mypage/ also show same error if I go http://myweb.com/mypage/mylink. "mypagename" directory content these pages css and js file.

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths for css/js etc. Add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: Better I am changing my directory name. Thank u sir.